# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

[image]
about code have a error is "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."

the function defined is:

```js
export const getShoppingCart = createAsyncThunk(
  "shoppingCart/getShoppingCart",
  async (jwt: string, thunkAPI) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://e9e0fde5-0f50-4037-af58-6b187be97f69.mock.pstmn.io/shoppingCart`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `bearer ${jwt}`,
        },
      }
    );
    return data.shoppingCartItems;
  }
);
```

The store type is:

```js
interface ShoppingCartState {
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  items: any[];
}

const initialState: ShoppingCartState = {
  loading: true,
  error: null,
  items: [],
};
```

The slice is:

```js
export const shoppingCartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingCart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getShoppingCart.pending.type]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getShoppingCart.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
      state.items = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [getShoppingCart.rejected.type]: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<string | null>
    ) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
   }
  })
```

My question is whether there is a more standardised solution to it? I am learning about it. Thanks!

I can fix it by Ternary Operators.  like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getShoppingCart(jwt ? jwt : ''))
  }, [jwt, dispatch])
```

Comment: that's probably all you need to do. you could also add an if statement to make sure jwt is defined.

Comment: In the future, please copy your code as text and not images. Second, it seems wherever s.user.token is defined it has a different data type than "string" which is what your function is looking for. You can try to change the getShoppingCart function to take a "string | null".

Comment: @Rick The fact that ternary operators and conditional judgements are basically equivalent

Comment: @MarcPfister Thank you for your suggestion, but the code does not show the error alert symbol. In future I will use code rather than images. The jwt in the code must be a string, not a null, so I can't use "string | null" where it is defined

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Seems like `user.token` can be `null`. Where is the type for the store defined?

Comment: I don't see `user.token` in the code you've added

Comment: @Konrad My thinking is that jwt is an asynchronous action function that must pass parameters, so it cannot be defined as null. perhaps my thinking is flawed. Think of ts too strictly

Comment: Your function is fine. The problem is that `useSelector(s => s.user.token)` returns `string | null`

Comment: @Konrad `user.token` is added to the store. just I not add it in the question. so long so complex

Comment: @Konrad I think soo. But I think my solution is disstandardised and low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Because `user.token` is `string | null` you cannot use it for `getShoppingCart` (which expects `string`)

## Fix

If you are sure its not null you can use a non null assertion i.e. `getShoppingCart(jwt!)`

## More

- [Non-Null Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro/strictnullchecks#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: Throwing an error would probably be more helpful than using `!`

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over...

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for, a standard specification. Maybe it's not. Unfortunately the question does repeat itself. At first I just didn't understand the other posts where this answer was given.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank the people who helped me. Although it did not help me to solve the problem. But provided me with a different way of thinking.
There are always those two self-righteous people who not only don't offer help, but give me 2 points less.
It seems I overestimated this site. I ended up solving the problem myself. Sharing it with you guys and those two smug people too.
Please give me back my precious points, don't expect 0+, 0 is fine！

```js
 const jwt = useSelector((s) => s.user.token) as string
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getShoppingCart(jwt))
  }, [jwt, dispatch])
```

Comment: `const jwt = useSelector((s) => s.user.token)!` would do the same. I still believe that the problem should be solved by declaring `user.token` type in a different way or with throwing an error

Comment: @Konrad yes! i tried,and success. but i cant understand. The two cents worth of superlatives, learned a trick.
It is likely that your understanding is correct, I will think about it again